# Results won't append from JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

The JSON file I am using: https://api.myjson.com/bins/49jw2

I am using `SwiftyJSON` for parsing.

The variable chores wont be populated outside the method `parseJson`

```
var chores: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tfWhat.delegate = self
    tfHowMuch.delegate = self

    loadJson()

    // wont even print
    for chore in self.chores {
        print("beschrijving: " + chore)
    }

    // prints 0
    print(chores.count)
}

func loadJson() -> Void {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/49jw2")

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let data = data {
                let json = JSON(data: data)

                self.parseJson(json["appdata"]["klusjes"][])
            } else {
                print("no data")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}

func parseJson(jsonObject : JSON) -> Void {
    for (_, value) in jsonObject {
        self.chores.append(value["beschrijving"].stringValue)
    }

    // prints:
    // beschrijving: Heg knippen bij de overburen
    // beschrijving: Auto van papa wassen
    for chore in self.chores {
        print("beschrijving: " + chore)
    }

    // prints:
    // 2
    print(chores.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call an *asynchronous method* like `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL` it gets executed *in the background*, so whatever you launch just after this instruction is actually executed *while* the background task is running, so your array is not populated *yet* when you look at it.

A simple way to overcome this mistake is to use a "callback": a closure that will be executed *once the data is available*.

For example, let's add a callback

```
(json: JSON)->()
```

to the `loadJson` method:

```
func loadJson(completion: (json: JSON)->())
```

and place the call where the data will be available:

```
func loadJson(completion: (json: JSON)->()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/49jw2")
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            if let data = data {
                // the callback executes *when the data is ready*
                completion(json: JSON(data: data))
            } else {
                print("no data")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

and use it with a trailing closure like this:

```
loadJson { (json) in
    // populate your array, do stuff with "json" here, this is the result of the callback
}
```